# How to use ~dp0 in a batch block on Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, windows-10

This seems like a bug to me...
I'm looking for an explanation or a pretty workaround...

When the script is located with a part ending with a closing parenthesis **`)`** as in **`Program Files(x86)`**, the script seems to "eat" the closing parenthesis.
Not happening on Windows 7, just on Windows 10...

```
@echo off
echo %%~dp0 outside the code block = %~dp0
if 0 EQU 0 (
    echo %%~dp0  inside the code block = %~dp0
)
```

You can try it with the script located in:

```
 - C:\Program Files (x86)\
 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Folder\
 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Folder\Another one\
 - C:\test-ok\test-not-ok-(1)\
```

Comment: Always quote paths: `"%~dp0"`

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Telling us we can try something is not as productive as posting your results.

Comment: Variables are expanded when the line is read. So your bracket closes the OPEN code block. So it errors because you have text after the close bracket. This is not a bug. This is compatibility with how the command prompt worked in the 1980s. CMD.exe will run MSDos batchfile without needing to change them. It has extra features built around that. There are two CMDs NT4 (which is also OS/2) and the newer Windows 2000 that we use. When you read help any reference to new behaviour is about NT4/Win2000 differences (see `start /?`).

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-the-evolution-of-the-windows-command-line/

Comment: @jwdonahue: will read, thank you. I admit I definitely need some more practice on asking questions here. Btw, nobody had to try anything unless they had a doubt about my post. The listed folders are explicitly showing a scheme on "path-part ENDING with a parenthesis".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the immediate `%`-expansion occurs before special characters like parentheses are recognised.

To prevent that you could quote the string, so special characters are protected:

```cmd
@echo off
echo %%~dp0 outside the code block = "%~dp0"
if 0 EQU 0 (
    echo %%~dp0  inside the code block = "%~dp0"
)
```

Of course the quotation mark might disturb. But you could use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to echo the path unquoted:

```cmd
@echo off
set "string=%~dp0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %%~dp0 outside the code block = !string!
if 0 EQU 0 (
    echo %%~dp0  inside the code block = !string!
)
endlocal
```

Alternatively you could use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to achieve another expansion phase after special character recognition:

```cmd
@echo off
for %%I in ("%~dp0") do (
    echo %%~dp0 outside the code block = %%~I
    if 0 EQU 0 (
        echo %%~dp0  inside the code block = %%~I
    )
)
```

Comment: Gratias! This is the most constructive approach with amazing examples to study/understand. Much appreciated.

Comment: So, why use if for a obviously true results, I’ve see others code/answer with this? I’m try understand this. Thx.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe, if I got you right, the `if 0 equ 0 ( ... )` is just there to have a code block, just for demonstration of the problem (mcve), it could also simply be `( ... )`; I'm sure in the actual script there is something more useful...